# How to run _update elasticsearch with external script

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run example update

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.text = \"some text\""
}'
```

(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), but got error `{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; ","status":400}`.

From this page http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html, I found out that I need to place my script (I called it `demorun.groovy`) and run it by name.
I did that, and now try to reference as

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "demorun.groovy"
}'
```

But still get same error. 
I suppose that reference it wrong. How to pass _update with external script?

My demorun.groovy:

```
ctx._source.text = \"some text\"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message you are receiving indicates that dynamic scripting is disabled, which is the default setting. You need to enable to get scripting to work:

> **Enabling dynamic scripting**
>
> We recommend running Elasticsearch behind an application or proxy,
>   which protects Elasticsearch from the outside world. If users are
>   allowed to run dynamic scripts (even in a search request), then they
>   have the same access to your box as the user that Elasticsearch is
>   running as. For this reason dynamic scripting is allowed only for
>   sandboxed languages by default.
>
> First, you should not run Elasticsearch as the root user, as this
>   would allow a script to access or do anything on your server, without
>   limitations. Second, you should not expose Elasticsearch directly to
>   users, but instead have a proxy application inbetween. If you do
>   intend to expose Elasticsearch directly to your users, then you have
>   to decide whether you trust them enough to run scripts on your box or
>   not. If you do, you can enable dynamic scripting by adding the
>   following setting to the config/elasticsearch.yml file on every node:
>
> script.disable_dynamic: false
>
> While this still allows execution of named scripts provided in the
>   config, or native Java scripts registered through plugins, it also
>   allows users to run arbitrary scripts via the API. Instead of sending
>   the name of the file as the script, the body of the script can be sent
>   instead.
>
> There are three possible configuration values for the
>   script.disable_dynamic setting, the default value is sandbox:
>
> true: all dynamic scripting is disabled, scripts must be placed in the
>   config/scripts directory.
>
> false: all dynamic scripting is enabled, scripts may be sent as
>   strings in requests.
>
> sandbox: scripts may be sent as strings for languages that are
>   sandboxed.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: This helps to make first script (specified right in _update query). But the reason it responds with "dynamic scripting is disabled" is other. Because referencing external script by name is actually _static_ scripting.

@Tom have you tried to remove .groovy extension when you are referencing a script?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the ES request above is that it's using the wrong format.

**Dynamic scripting** (i.e. inline scripting):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
  "script" : "ctx._source.text = \"some text\""
}'
```

**Static scripting** (i.e. offline scripting):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
  "script" : {
    "lang": "groovy",
    "script_file": "some-name",
    "params": {
      "foo": "some text"
    }
  }
}'
```

And you are supposed to put

```
ctx._source.text = foo
```

into `.../elasticsearch/config/scripts/some-name.groovy` to reproduce almost the same functionality. Actually, much better because you don't need to open up ES to dynamic scripting, and you get arguments passing.

Answer (score 2):

In elasticsearch 2.0, `script.disable_dynamic: false` not work, because:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   script.disable_dynamic is not a supported setting, replac e with
>   fine-grained script settings. Dynamic scripts can be enabled for all
>   languages and all operations by replacing `script.disable_dynamic:
>   false` with `s cript.inline: on` and `script.indexed: on` in
>   elasticsearch.yml

as error says , you need set below in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue and resolved it by adding the following code to the elasticsearch.yml file in config folder:

`script.disable_dynamic: false`